# ps file calling 'length' on a procedure

Tags: postscript

I have a ps file with this line:

```
^ab {@st0 setfont}^ap
```

When `^ab` is defined here:

```
/^ab{1000 array 0 1000}bind def
```

and `^ap` is defined here:

```
/^ap{
    dup length 3 index add dup 3 index lt{
        4 index exch 6 2 roll exch
        4 1 roll putinterval
    }{
        3 -1 roll 1000 add dup
        {array}stopped{
            pop pop pop
            3 1 roll 0 exch getinterval
            cvx bind
            1000 array dup 0 4 -1 roll put
            dup 1 /exec load put
            2 1000 4 -1 roll ^ap
        }{
            dup 0 8 -1 roll putinterval
            dup 6 -2 roll putinterval
            3 1 roll
        }ifelse
    }ifelse
}bind def`
```

So if I'm reading it correctly, `^ab` creates on the stack an array of size 1000 and 2 integers: 0 and 1000.
Then the procedure `{@st0 setfont}` is saved on the stack so the stack looks like this:

`[array, 0, 1000, {@st0 setfont}]`

Then `^ap` is called with `dup` which duplicates the procedure on the stack and then `length` is called which should get the length of the most top item on the stack which is the duplicated procedure, but it doesn't make sense to me. `length` should be called only on a string, array or dictionary. So what's going on here?
Or am I interpreting it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A procedure **is** an array. Usually a packed array but that's not relevant. What happens here is that it gets the length of the array `{@st0 setfont}` which is 2.

Try sticking a `pstack` or `dup ==` into the definition of the /^ap procedure, after the length.

Answer (score 2):

Ken has already answered the basic question, but I hope my comments are helpful to OP understanding this code.

My educated guess is that the abbreviations are ab="array begin" and ap="append".

It appears to be maintaining three objects together, almost like a tuple but all three are on the stack. The array itself, the "write head" position, the capacity. Then it fills the array until position>capacity. Then it gets interesting. It tries to allocate a larger array and keep going but if it cannot allocate a larger array for whatever reason, it wraps what it has in `{ ... } exec` and makes a new small array containing just that.

Pretty clever. Where is this code from?

Comment: Thanks.
It's from an HP office printer.